# MaxRequestWorkers setting

Tags: apache, vps, plesk

I have a vps with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and plesk 12.01

Where I have 8 active domains.

Many times I find myself off the http service logs the following error:

```
server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting


<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>



<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

I tried different configurations, but nothing.

Just start the apache service sites go quietly, after 2-3 minutes they all go off. But the cpu and ram are completely free.

In plesk I only active mpm_prefor
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to increase MaxRequestWorkers value on your server to 250 and monitor your Apache services logs, if you are getting same issues that meas your server is under DDOS attack and due to that you are getting this issues,